# Use applescript to export files to pdf

Tags: pdf, applescript, export

I'm working on my first AppleScript (2.5) and can't seem to resolve my issue here.

I'm trying to open each markdown file in a folder and export to PDF. Opening the file with the specified application works, but I get 'The variable PDF is not defined' before the export happens.

I've tried four or five different sets of commands, from permutations on the save command to trying to use 'export' as some have suggested, but this form here appears to be the closest I've come to success. (Anytime I use export I get "Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier" and the word 'export' highlighted)

I appreciate any insight

```
tell application "Finder"
    set sourceFolder to "Path:To:SourceFolder"
    set MDFiles to files of folder sourceFolder whose name extension is "md"
end tell
repeat with f in MDFiles
    set filePath to f as text
    set newFilePath to (text 1 thru -2 of filePath) & "pdf"
    tell application "MacDown"
        open f
        save f in file newFilePath as PDF
        close f saving no
    end tell
end repeat
```

Comment: Look into the dictionary of `MacDown` to figure which parameters the `save` command provides.

Comment: Thanks! I will now google how to do that :)

Comment: In Script Editor press ⇧⌘O and select the application in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following @vadian's advice, it appears that the application does not have the ability to save to PDF.

Comment: If you really need this, you can try the "Print to PDF" capability which all OSX apps have. I don't have example code otherwise I'd post an answer – but have a look at the following link and google around on the topic http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=36646